# can we use SSML tags with confirmation event in dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot, ssml

I have an intent where I am confirming the customer phone number, but instead of saying it as characters, agent says it as cardinal

customerNumber is 1234567890

```
conv.ask(new Confirmation(`You told ${customerNumber}, is that right please confirm?`));
```

I tried this too but it didn't work

```
conv.ask(new Confirmation(`<speak>You told <say-as interpret-as='characters'>${customerNumber}</say-as> is that right please confirm?</speak>`));
```

SSML works fine with a simple response but it is not working with a confirmation response. How can I have it speak the number as characters?

Answer (score 0):

No, the [Confirmation Helper](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers#confirmation) only accepts text.

Since you're using Dialogflow, you don't need to use the Confirmation Helper. You can send the reply as a normal "simple" response using SSML and either use [predefined followup-intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents) for "yes" and "no", or use the same phrases as those predefined intents in an Entity Type that you use in your own Intent.